# Create a df of shape (4,2) from df with shape (2,3) by stacking first two columns and repeating the 3rd

Tags: python, pandas

I want to reshape a dataframe df1

```
r1c1 |r1c2 | r1c3
r2c1 |r2c2 | r2c3
```

to

```
r1c1 | r1c3
r2c1 | r2c3
r1c2 | r1c3
r2c2 | r2c3
```

The second column is to be stacked on the first column and the (original) 3rd column is to be repeated.

Whats the best way to do that in `pandas`?

Comment: Is the row order important?

Comment: No - its only important that eventually, each of the initial entries of col1 and col2 is mapped to the correct entry of the original col3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***`pandas`***

```
df1.set_index(2).unstack().reset_index(1).iloc[:, ::-1]

      0     2
0  r1c1  r1c3
0  r2c1  r2c3
1  r1c2  r1c3
1  r2c2  r2c3
```

---

***`numpy`***

```
v = df1.values
np.hstack([v[:, :2].reshape(-1, 1), v[:, 2].repeat(2)[:, None]])

array([['r1c1', 'r1c3'],
       ['r1c2', 'r1c3'],
       ['r2c1', 'r2c3'],
       ['r2c2', 'r2c3']], dtype=object)
```

***setup***

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({0: ['r1c1', 'r2c1'], 1: ['r1c2', 'r2c2'], 2: ['r1c3', 'r2c3']})
print(df1)

      0     1     2
0  r1c1  r1c2  r1c3
1  r2c1  r2c2  r2c3
```

Comment: follow-up question: How can this be generalized to stacking the first n columns and repeating the (n+1)th?

Comment: @user1934212 `v[:, :n]` and `repeat(n)` should be the target components to change for generalization.